How can the errors in this Solid Geometry code be corrected?
As shown in the figure, in the cube ABCD-A1B1C1D1, point N lies on BD, point M lies on B1C, and CM = DN. Construct the intersection of plane MNB1 with the cube ABCD-A1B1C1D1 to obtain the cross-section.

How can the errors in this code be corrected?
Clear["`*"]
Unprotect[C, D, N];
{A, A1, D, D1, B, B1, C, C1} = Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3];
{M = C + t (B1 - C), N = D + t (B - D)}
normalVector = Cross[M - N, B1 - N]
plane = Hyperplane[normalVector, B1]
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{{FaceForm[], Cuboid[A, C1]}, {Cyan, 
    RegionIntersection[plane, Cuboid[A, C1]]}, {MapThread[
     Text[Style[#1, 12, 
        FontFamily -> "Times"], #2, {-1, -2}] &, {{"A", "B", "C", "D",
        "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "M", "N"}, {A, B, C, D, A1, B1, C1, 
       D1, M, N}}]}, {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@M, Point@N, 
    Line[{B1, C}], Dashed, Line[{M, N}], Line[{B, D}]}}, 
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500], {t, 0, 1}]


Clear["`*"]
{a, a1, d, d1, b, b1, c, c1} = Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3];
m[t_] := c + t  (b1 - c);
n[t_] := d + t  (b - d);
normalVector[t_] := Cross[m[t] - n[t], b1 - n[t]];
plane[t_] := Hyperplane[normalVector[t], b1]
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{{FaceForm[], Cuboid[a, c1]}, {Cyan, 
    RegionIntersection[plane[t], Cuboid[a, c1]]}, {MapThread[
     Text[Style[#1, 12, 
        FontFamily -> "Times"], #2, {-1, -2}] &, {{"A", "B", "C", "D",
        "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "M", "N"}, {a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, 
       d1, m[t], n[t]}}]}, {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[m[t]], 
    Point[n[t]], Line[{b1, c}], Dashed, Line[{m[t], n[t]}], 
    Line[{b, d}]}}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500], {t, 0, 1}]


