Why can't an image be drawn?
Why doesn't this code draw the graph of the equation?
l1 = a x - 2 y == 2 a - 4; l2 = 2 x + a^2 y == 2 a^2 + 4;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate /@ {l1, l2}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], {a, 0, 2}]


Manipulate[  l1 = a x - 2 y == 2 a - 4; l2 = 2 x + a^2 y == 2 a^2 + 4;   ContourPlot[Evaluate[{l1, l2}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], {a, 0, 2}]

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/306059/1871 I don't see your effort in understanding the answer you've obtained. (-1)

And there exist numbers of duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23734/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25087/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/302596/1871 There should be more.

I would prefer to do it this way. The control variable, in your case a should always be local to the Manipulate. And add TrackingSymbols on it.  To do this, add new control variable to use for tracking, call it a0 and replace the global a in the expression with it.

ClearAll["Global`*"]
L1 = a x - 2 y == 2 a - 4; L2 = 2 x + a^2 y == 2 a^2 + 4;

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[{L1, L2} /. a -> a0], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}],
 {{a0, 0, "a0"}, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a0}]

This is more safe.
